# Block Certain Websites in IP Range Through Router

Tags: networking, firewall

I have a MikroTik Router 951Ui-2HnD that connects my computers with the ISP, and want to block Youtube and Facebook but only on a few computers.

I created a Layer7 Protocol with:
**Name :** Denied Websites
**Regexp :**^.+(facebook.com|youtube).*$

Then I created a Firewall Filter Rule with this configuration:
**Chain :** forward
**In.Interface :** ether1
**Layer7 Protocol :** Denied Websites
**Action :** Drop

With this configuration the 2 websites are blocked on all the computers.

I then created a Address List with:
**Name :** Forbidden
**Address :** 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.20 (which I the range of the IPs where i want to block this 2 Websites)

I Add this Address List to Src.Address List of the Firewall Rule ,but doing so will let all the computers access Facebook and Youtube.

Am I missing something? What do I need to do to block this websites only to this range of IPs `192.168.1.1`-`192.168.1.20`?

Answer (score 1):

Dear you dont need any address in and also no need of doing this you do this only Name : Denied Websites
Regexp :^.+(facebook.com|youtube).*$

Then i created a Firewall Filter Rule with this configuration :
Chain : forward
In.Interface : ether1
Layer7 Protocol : Denied Websites
Action : Drop
except 
With this configuration the 2 websites are blocked for all the computers.

I then created a Address List with :
Name : Forbidden
Address : 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.20 (which i the range of the IPs where i want to block this 2 Websites)

I Add this Address List to Src.Address List of the Firewall Rule ,but doing so will let all the computers access Facebook and Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to filter on src addresses in your lan you'll need to filter on your LAN link/port (ie. ether-2).
As your L7 filter stands it's looking at Ether-1.  By the time your outbound traffic hits ether-1 it's been masqueraded so the src addrss is that of the router not the machine that sent it.